# PWA minimal service worker just for trigger the install button?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

What is the minimal service worker just for trigger the install button?

I don't want cacheing anything and the app can't works in offline mode, but i want allow users to create a shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: There are heuristics to determine whether or not your app works offline.  While a basic service worker without caching may get around the problem today, the standards allow the browser to change this behavior as they see fit.  Browser vendors seem to be doing their hardest to dictate how things will work.  It's best practice to have *some* offline experience anyway, even if that's just a splash screen stating that the user is offline and that they need to connect to use your app.

Answer (score 19):

The "ultra" minimal service worker is

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function() {
    return;
});
```

No need to do something into fetch method

Answer (score 9):

Seems like the minimal service worker would be this one

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

Taken from the [Google Developers PWA documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#network_only)

Comment: Note that this will make your site a little slower as requests will have to wait for the service worker to wake up and for the listener to rerequest.